# Call AngularJS function of controller by jQuery to update master controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have index.html as Master Page and indexController.js.
index.html has a partial body

```
<div ng-view=""></div>
```

to load partial view, for example, login.html

The pure AngularJS project use semantic-ui. login.html has form login with implementing FormValidation of semantic-ui.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.ui.form')
    .form({
        // some setting....
        onSuccess: function (event, fields) {
            var scope = angular.element($('#loginForm')).scope();

            scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.login();
            });

            return false;
        }
    })
```

});

In index.html, I have logic to hide or show menu

```
<a class="ui item" ng-hide="!authentication.isAuth" href="#/assets">Asset</a>
```

and indexController.js

```
$scope.authentication = authService.authentication;
```

How can I update information of indexController to show or hide menu on it?

Comment: You have to define your form function in contrroller. So you can update scope.

Comment: Hi @hurricane, I don't get your point?

Answer (score 1):

Add your ('ui.form') function to indexController and then call it.

```
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
.controller('indexController ', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.authentication.isAuth = false;

  $scope.loginControl = function() {
    $('.ui.form')
        .form({
            onSuccess: function (event, fields) {
                $scope.authentication.isAuth = true;
        })
    });
  };
}]);
```

When you call `$scope.loginControl()` if it is succes your div will be opened.

Comment: Thank @hurricane, the big mistake of me is missing using indexController in index.html, so shame :(. But your code is look good.